# Did Wolfram Alpha make this term up?

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

So I'm currently taking a Trigonometry class and I'm using the iOS version of the Wolfram-Alpha app to assist me with some of the more mundane calculations (Pythagorean Theorem, etc) and I've come across something rather peculiar. At some point, it suggested a related term called "fairradian" and when I tapped that Wolfram-Alpha dutifully informed me that a fairradian (or Frad for short) was a unit of measure equal to 10<sup>15</sup> radians. I hadn't ever heard of the prefix *fair-* so I looked it up. What do you know? Nothing. Nothing on Wikipedia and nothing at all on Google. Absolutely zip. WA claims it is an SI unit of measure with the "physical quantity" of "plane angle."

It was at this point that I sent a feedback to WA asking for clarification on the term. Where it came from, etc. I included my email address and got an automated response to my email that they had received the message. That was two months ago and I heard nothing. Today, I decided to see if the term still existed on WA and it does, however there are additions to it's information!

Now it has a section titled "Unit status" with three entries. "Proposed," "never used," and "whimsical." I found this very interesting, but there still was no information on it's origins. Who proposed this unit? When? Why isn't it anywhere on Google?

Was this unit actually proposed at some point or is Wolfram-Alpha straight up making this up? Is it perhaps a piece of deliberate misinformation in order to detect copyright infringement in the same way print encyclopedias put in a fabricated article or mapmakers would include phantom roads in order to detect whether or not their work was copied? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: It certainly isn't an SI unit.  The prefix for $10^{15}$ is **peta**, not **fair**.

Comment: If that were an SI unit, so would be fairmeter - which WA rederects to taximeter. Go figure. (Then again, they add a link to an interpretation as unit $10^{15}\,\mathrm m$. But as Robert said, that would be petameters.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's why I'm leaning toward WA making things up. Looking up taximeter Google yields nothing but the fare meters used by taxi cabs. Even expanding the search with the additional terms "unit of measure" or "SI standard" gives nothing about an actual unit of measure. This throws WA's credibility out the window if there are more of these unknown terms in their database. How deep does the rabbit hole go?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Frad is used in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=UC_1_804BXgC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=Frad+SI+unit&source=bl&ots=IW1xqlnNFD&sig=SYoC_kUhhrSLFdvXw79JXvMhnWA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P4LBVPm6AcfIsAThpYKgCw&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Frad%20SI%20unit&f=false) to refer to "femtoradians," which are obviously quite smaller.